# Make Windows file shares default to domain authentication on the server side?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

We are retiring an old domain controller that some genius has set a file share up on. This file share is used heavily by devices that aren't domain joined.

As the share resides on the DC itself, there's no local user database so the clients have been successfully authenticating with just a domain username and password.

The problem arises when we attempt to move said share to a non-DC. If the clients use just their username, authentication will fail. They need to use 'domain\user' or 'user@domain' for auth to succeed.

I assume it is trying to authenticate against the local users on the server.

If this is the case can anyone think of a way to set the implied prefix/UPN on the server side to work around this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Common things to check that could cause issues would be:

- `Credential Vault` or `Credential Manager` for stored logins
- Matching local usernames (`Administrator`) between non-domain clients and the domain servers.